# Windows Phone 8.1 referencing a C++ dll fails

Tags: c#, c++, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Start Visual Studio 2013.

New project: `Visual C# / Store Apps / Windows Phone App -> Select "Blank App"`. 
C# WP8.1 App1 is created

Add Project: `Visual C++ / Store Apps / Windows Phone App -> Select "DLL (Windows Phone)"`. 
C++ WP8.1 Dll1 is created

Go to App1 and try to add reference to Dll1 -> **Error: A Reference to Dll1 could not be added.**

Why does that happen?
I need to expose to Windows Phone a C++ component that we re-use on iPhone and Android, this works in Windows Phone 8.0 but not in 8.1 (Store) - does work in 8.1 Silverlight though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - I need to create a Windows Runtime Component app - 
This is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755833.aspx

Thanks FoggyDay for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/30/get-your-libraries-ready-for-windows-phone-8-1.aspx

> Apps that target Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 can consume existing
>   libraries and NuGet packages as-is – after all, it’s still Windows
>   Phone Silverlight – just an updated version.
>
> Apps that target the new Windows Phone 8.1 platform can only consume
>   libraries and NuGet packages that are built for Windows Phone 8.1. But
>   don’t worry – it’s easy to update your libraries to include support
>   for Windows Phone 8.1.

The article then discusses several alternatives for your libraries.

Comment: Sorry does not help - The Library I create from Visual Studio is in C++, not a portable library (as referenced by the article) and is using the Platform Toolset Windows Phone 8.1 (v120_wp81).

Comment: Q: Is there anything else in the error message?  Please update your post with the complete error text.  More information would definitely be helpful. Q: Is your application written in C#?  Is "adding a reference" in the project necessary?  Perhaps you can just add a `[DllImport]` in your  code?